# SwiftUI: Dynamically move navigationBar items on List scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have [custom navigationBarItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6EDt.png) attached to my NavigationBar (the SF Symbols chevron) and when I go to scroll through my items in the ScrollView, the NavigationBar will [collapse to .inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxoq4.gif) and my items stay put.

Is it possible to anchor the [chevron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6EDt.png) to the right of the .navigationBarTitle or dynamically move the items upon scroll?

Here's my current code:

```
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            eventView()
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading:
            Button(action: {
                // action
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle")
                    .font(.system(size: 21, weight: .regular))
                    .offset(x: 169, y: 47)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(...))
                }
            )
            .navigationBarTitle("Upcoming")
    }
```

(I'm new to SwiftUI, I know it's not up to scratch)

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what you want, but the reason for this behavior is your offset.

Try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(UIFont.familyNames, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        // action
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                        Text("Upcoming")
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle")
                             .font(.system(size: 21, weight: .regular))
                        //     .offset(x: 169, y: 47)
                             .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                        }
                    }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best thing possible at the moment (or creating a custom view). I guess this is just a limitation of SwiftUI for now. Thanks!